# Perl regex match the exact word

Tags: regex, perl

I have two strings, one is without parentheses, the other is with parentheses.

**apple**

**(apple)**

What I am going to match is **apple** (without parentheses) rather than **(apple)**

```
$string =~ m/\bapple\b/
```

didn't work. It matches both.

Comment: What do you want to match, word with in parentheses or one without?

Comment: What about `(?<!\S)apple(?!\S)`?

Comment: I think you ask for whitespace boundaries, use `m/(?<!\S)apple(?!\S)/`

Comment: @revo Thanks for you quick answer. It works!!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome, It works. Thanks for telling me the whitespace boundaries. :)